# Delta method confusion

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, delta-method

I am supposed to use the delta method to find the limiting distribution for $$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\overline{X}_n}{1-\overline{X}_n} - \frac{E(X)}{1-E(X)}\right)$$ where $f(x, \theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}I\{x\in (0,1)\}$.  I'm utterly lost on how to do this, as this doesn't line up with how he briefly explained the Delta method in class.

Comment: What do you know about the delta method?

Comment: I know that $\sqrt{n}(h(\overline{x})-h(\theta)) \to N(0, h'(x)^2\theta)$ or something like that

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Univariate_delta_method

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

let we know by central limit theorem
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu_{x})\rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$$

By using Taylor series we get
$$\sqrt{n}\left(h(\bar{X})-h(\mu_{x})\right)=\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}-\mu_{x})h^{\prime}(\mu_{x})
+\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}-\mu_{x})^2\frac{h^{\prime \prime}(\mu_{x})}{2!}+\cdots$$

lets we use  an approximation like (if $h^{\prime}(\mu_{x})\neq 0$)

$$\sqrt{n}\left(h(\bar{X})-h(\mu_{x})\right)\cong  \color{red}{\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}-\mu_{x})}h^{\prime}(\mu_{x})\rightarrow N(0,?) $$

Comment: That would go to $N(0,(h'(\mu_x))^2\sigma^2)$ I believe

Comment: I think, its look good to me.

Comment: Okay, so how do I extend that to the entire Taylor expansion?

Comment: Usually you just use the first term of Taylor series. But some times $h^{\prime}(\mu_{x})= 0$ so you use the second term. It is depend on the  situation.

Comment: Oh okay.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.